# Can not install pyhdf on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

When I try to install pyhdf, this error happens:

```
sudo easy_install -f pyhdf-0.8.3.tar.gz pyhdf
Searching for pyhdf
Best match: pyhdf 0.8.3
Processing pyhdf-0.8.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-Q0FIMR/pyhdf-0.8.3/setup.cfg
Running pyhdf-0.8.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Q0FIMR/pyhdf-0.8.3/egg-dist-tmp-wXq_6K
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg’:
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c:859:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c: At top level:
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c:3048:17: fatal error: hdf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg’:
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c:859:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c: At top level:
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c:3048:17: fatal error: hdf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.o" failed with exit status 1
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
  from numpy.distutils import log
```

Any idea what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to install `libhdf4-dev` package.

And instead of using `sudo` to install packages into your system, spend some time to read about [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: Sometimes it's not very straightforward to install C based python libraries such as numpy and probably this one on Ubuntu. I've installed them on Arch without any pain using PIP though.

Comment: Thank you. The new error happens: from numpy.distutils import log. I do not know why.

Answer (score 2):

Even with libhdf4-dev package you can encounter the problem with missing hdf.h file(I did). It seems that code setup.py (in the installation archive) does not properly handle the environment variable which specifies where the HDF4 library is.

I solved the problem by following the step-by-step instruction of http://pysclint.sourceforge.net/pyhdf/install.html but you must add in the command line your hdf library instead of exporting it:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/hdf/  [note it may be different in your system ]

sudo python setup.py install -i $INCLUDE_DIRS
```

Same problem for the NOSZIP variable if you don't have/want szlib, but here I modified setup.py on line 29:

```
szip_installed=False
```

Then installation works fine.

Comment: Great answer. It's a pity they haven't fixed setup.py.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue , you first need to install *hdf* development package .

`sudo apt-get install libhdf4-dev`

Comment: Thank you, I did this but still have errors. The new error happens: 
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
  from numpy.distutils import log
 I do not know why.

Comment: In case that you don't want to use _virtualenv_ and you are installing to global namespace , you could try installing ubuntu package `python-h5py` .

Comment: @Alexander that's for hdf5, not hdf4.